# How to save Binary Data as a jpg image in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, image, binary-data

I have an api which returns Binary Media Data (The data contains an image), I want to send this data to a file. I am able to do this via CURL command using -o. But I am not able to do the same in node js. Please help.

Comment: You may like to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/request module

Comment: using pipe method? By "send" here I mean storing data in a file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use request module something like following

```
const fs = require('fs');
const request = require('request');

request
  .get('http://example.com/image.png')
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.png'))
```

Comment: Great, If any answer works, You should accept that answer this will help to other as well